# How do I transpose data from multiple columns into a row?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a Google Sheet to input multiple choice answers and I'd like to map the answers (Output Column in my student sheets) to a summary sheet. I have separate tabs for each student. I've used transpose, but this formula removes blank cells.

`=transpose({Student1!B2:B4;Student1!E7:E81;Student1!I7:I66})`

I need to show any blank cells since this means the student didn't provide an answer to the question. Ultimately, the ImportMap tab will be exported to a CSV to be graded.

Student1 maps to row 1 of ImportMap
Student2 maps to row 2 of ImportMap
Student3 maps to row 3 of ImportMap

Also, is it possible to create a command that clears all of the students' answers from the different tabs? Students' answers are located in the Output Column of each student tab. For example, E7:E81.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/120SI4Zo6z-ZFAg_MYEQwbOAzzhaXHohDQAEIFFXOoRU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what do you mean by "formula removes blank cells"? it doesnt

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Actually my original formula works. I made a mistake in stating that blank cells were ignored. They do show up in transpose.

Answer (score 0):

try in A1 and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE({
 INDIRECT("Student"&ROW(A1)&"!B2:B4"); 
 INDIRECT("Student"&ROW(A1)&"!E7:E81"); 
 INDIRECT("Student"&ROW(A1)&"!I7:I66"); 
 INDIRECT("Student"&ROW(A1)&"!M7:M46"); 
 INDIRECT("Student"&ROW(A1)&"!Q7:Q46")}))
```

[image]